# symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration

Tags: c++

I've got a header in which my base problem is with the `using` keyword.

```
#ifndef SHAPEFACTORY_H__
#define SHAPEFACTORY_H__

#include <istream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include "shape.h"


/* thrown when a shape cannot be read from a stream */
template<class T>
class WrongFormatException { };

template<class T>
class ShapeFactory
{
public:
    using createShapeFunction=Shape<T>*()(void);
    static void registerFunction(const std::string &, const createShapeFunction *);
    static Shape<T> *createShape(const std::string &);
    static Shape<T> *createShape(std::istream &);
private:
    std::map<std::string, createShapeFunction *> creationFunctions;
    ShapeFactory();
    static ShapeFactory<T> *getShapeFactory();
};

#endif
```

And I've got some errors which I can't resolve.

```
1>shapefactory.h(21): error C2873: 'createShapeFunction' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>shapefactory.h(29) : see reference to class template instantiation 'ShapeFactory<T>' being compiled
1>shapefactory.h(21): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '='
1>shapefactory.h(21): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>shapefactory.h(22): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>shapefactory.h(22): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '*'
1>shapefactory.h(26): error C2065: 'createShapeFunction' : undeclared identifier
1>shapefactory.h(26): error C2059: syntax error : '>'
1>shapefactory.h(29): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
1>shapefactory.h(29): fatal error C1004: unexpected end-of-file found
```

Any idea would be great.

Comment: Change `Shape<T>*()(void)` to `Shape<T>*(void)`; the former declares a function returning a function.

Comment: I did that before and I've got the same errors.

Comment: What compiler/version (VS judging by error messages, but version is harder to guess :))? Take a look at support for different features in different versions of VS [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx). In particular you want to look for 'Alias templates'

Comment: I use VS 2012. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the compiler does not support the alias decladation. Substitute it for a typedef declaration. For example (at least the code is compiled)

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
class Shape;

template<class T>
class ShapeFactory
{
public:
    typedef Shape<T>* createShapeFunction(void);
    static void registerFunction(const std::string &, const createShapeFunction *);
    static Shape<T> *createShape(const std::string &);
    static Shape<T> *createShape(std::istream &);
private:
    std::map<std::string, createShapeFunction *> creationFunctions;
    ShapeFactory();
    static ShapeFactory<T> *getShapeFactory();
};



int main() 
{

    return 0;
}
```