# Template argument deduction failed, using function pointers as argument

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2012

I've written a number of templated functions. Example:

```
template <typename T>
inline int Foo(T* t, unsigned char** p, size_t* size, size_t (*MyHandler)(T*))
{
    ...
}

template <>
inline int Foo<Bar>(Bar* t, unsigned char** p, size_t* size, size_t (*MyHandler)(Bar*))
{
    ...
}
```

If I call these functions with explicit template arguments then all works well, i.E.

```
Foo<Bar>(&myBar, pBuffer, size, FooFoo<Bar>);
```

`FooFoo<T>` be a different templated function

It would be highly advantageous if a user would not need to keep track of types. So I'd like to use the following syntax:

```
Foo(&myBar, pBuffer, size, FooFoo);
```

However, this line is causing a pair of

- C2784: could not deduce template argument for 'T *' from 'Bar *'
- C2796: cannot use function template 'size_t FooFoo(T *) as a function argument

As with `Foo`, there exists a specialization `FooFoo<Bar>`

To my knowledge, it should be possible to have T deduced, because of the first argument, which is of type `T*` - Or is that function pointer messing with the deduction?

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

**Update 3** 
A MCVS as per the request with changes suggested by @Yakk which finally works!

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Bar
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};


template<class T>struct id_t{typedef T type;}; 

template <typename T>
inline size_t FooFoo(T* t)
{
    printf("FooFoo calculating size of T...\r\n", sizeof(T));
    return sizeof(T);
}

template <>
inline size_t FooFoo<Bar>(Bar* t)
{
    printf("FooFoo calculating size of Bar...\r\n", sizeof(Bar));
    return sizeof(Bar);
}

template <typename T>
inline int Foo(T* t, unsigned char** p, size_t* size, typename id_t<size_t (*)(T*)>::type MyHandler)
{
    printf("Foo telling size of T: %u\r\n", MyHandler(t));
    return 0;
}

template <>
inline int Foo<Bar>(Bar* t, unsigned char** p, size_t* size, typename id_t<size_t (*)(Bar*)>::type MyHandler)
{
    printf("Foo telling size of Bar: %u\r\n", MyHandler(t));
    return 0;
}



int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int i;
    Bar myBar;

    Foo<Bar>(&myBar, nullptr, 0, FooFoo<Bar>); //  works
    Foo<int>(&i, nullptr, 0, FooFoo<int>); // works

    Foo(&myBar, nullptr, 0, FooFoo<Bar>); //  works
    Foo(&i, nullptr, 0, FooFoo<int>); // works


    Foo(&myBar, nullptr, 0, FooFoo);    // error C2896: 'int Foo(T *,unsigned char **,size_t *,size_t (__cdecl *)(T *))' : cannot use function template 'size_t FooFoo(T *)' as a function argument
                                        // error C2784: 'int Foo(T *,unsigned char **,size_t *,size_t (__cdecl *)(T *))' : could not deduce template argument for 'T *' from 'Bar *'

    Foo(&i, nullptr, 0, FooFoo);        // error C2896: 'int Foo(T *,unsigned char **,size_t *,size_t (__cdecl *)(T *))' : cannot use function template 'size_t FooFoo(T *)' as a function argument
                                        //error C2784: 'int Foo(T *,unsigned char **,size_t *,size_t (__cdecl *)(T *))' : could not deduce template argument for 'T *' from 'int *'

    return 0;
}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Just curious, but have you tried `Foo(&myBar, pBuffer, size, FooFoo<Bar>);`?

Comment: Cannot reproduce with g++ 5.1 (TDM), clang or VC2015 - Please add a [Minimum, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and detailed information about your compiler to your post so that we do not have to make guess on what is wrong.

Comment: @Holt I've updated with details, the compiler is MSVC 2012

Comment: @antipattern Thanks for the update, you have a small mistake in your MCVE (first return should be `sizeof(T)` not `T` I guess). I do not have MSVC2012 but I confirm the example you gave compiles and runs fine with MSVC2015, don't know if it standard thought...

Comment: @Holt Thank you for testing, thats a good thing to know, as I only have this old version here and nothing else. I was worried it was not possible after all.

Comment: Works for me using g++ 5.3.0  and clang++ 3.7.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All arguments have equal weight when deducing, and are deduced independently. To block using a particular argument for deduction, do this:

```
template<class T>struct id_t{typedef T type;};
template<class T>using block_deduction=typename id_t<T>::type;
```

Now take `size_t (*MyHandler)(T*)` and make it:

```
block_deduction<size_t (*)(T*)> MyHandler
```

Or in a non-C++11 compiler:

```
typename id_t<size_t (*)(T*)>::type MyHandler
```

What this does is put the `MyHandler` argument's type into a non-deduced context.  As such, the compiler does not try, and instead uses the deduction of the first argument to determine `T`.  This then generates the type of `MyHandler`.  The overload set you pass is then resolved based on the signature, and everything works (probably).

Comment: Thank you for adding an explanation. Do I have to use the block_deduction also in case of the specialized Foo<Bar> or just when declaring the generic templated Foo? Because Intellisense shows an error when I use it in the declaration of specialized Foo ("No instance of function declaration matches the specified type").

Comment: Apparently my version of Visual Studio does not support this. Too bad :/ Is there any way of getting rid of the `using` keyword ?

Comment: @antipattern Use `typename id_t<size_t (*)(T*)>::type MyHandler` instead of what is proposed by Yakk at the end.

Comment: @Holt There occors an error already in the first line:  error C2873: 'type' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration. I've found a vaguely similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23374003/symbol-cannot-be-used-in-a-using-declaration, but was unable to make it work for me.

Comment: @antipattern You need to completely remove the `using` declaration and use what I propose instead of `block_deduction<size_t (*)(T*)> MyHandler`.

Comment: @anti C++03 version added.  Two changes, removing `using`

Comment: I've updated my MCVE accordingly with the errors occuring. I've likely made some mistake. I am not sure if the `typename id_t<size_t (*)(T*)>::type MyHandler` has to go into the function headers? Otherwise the compiler complains about unknown T...

Comment: Alright, now I got it right. I needed the `template<class T>struct id_t{typedef T type;};` and `typename id_t<size_t (*)(T*)>::type MyHandler` to make it work. I suggest adding the first line to the non-C++11 example, to prevent other people to follow my mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not the deduction of `T=Bar` for `Foo` - it's the deduction for `FooFoo`.

Comment: Okay, I did have that suspicion too. On the other hand, if I hover Foo in the second call, then Intellisense does show a correctly deduced signature: `Foo<Bar>(Bar* t, unsigned char pBuffer, size_t size, size_t (*MyHandler)(Bar*))`.